# django serialize make a custom display format

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

This is My code :

```
for i in Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,theater_id=theaterid,movietime__gte=get_today()):
    if i.mvtype not in movietimes:
        movietimes[i.mvtype] = []
    movietimes[i.mvtype].append({i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') : i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')})
```

And the result is :

```
"3D": [ 
    {
        "2015-01-29": "2015-01-29T01:20:00.000000Z"
    }, 
    {
        "2015-01-29": "2015-01-29T03:10:00.000000Z"
    }, 
    {
        "2015-01-29": "2015-01-29T05:10:00.000000Z"
    }, 

    {
        "2015-01-28": "2015-01-28T17:10:00.000000Z"
    }, 
    {
        "2015-01-28": "2015-01-28T01:20:00.000000Z"
    }, 
]
```

But what I want like :

```
"3D": [ 
    {
        "2015-01-29": {
                    "2015-01-29T01:20:00.000000Z",
                    "2015-01-29T03:10:00.000000Z"
                    "2015-01-29T05:10:00.000000Z"
        }, 

        "2015-01-28": {
                    "2015-01-28T17:10:00.000000Z"
                    "2015-01-28T01:20:00.000000Z"
        }, 
    }   
]
```

How can I do this , 
Please help me

Comment: But that format makes no sense, assuming you're intending to serialize this to JSON. Shouldn't the details for each date be in an array, not a set?

Comment: sorry,I can't get your meaning,what is the array like?

Comment: With square brackets, like you have around the members of the outer 3D element.

Comment: OK I got it ,so how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
for i in Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,theater_id=theaterid,movietime__gte=get_today()):
    if i.mvtype not in movietimes:
        movietimes[i.mvtype] = {}
    dt = i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if dt not in movietimes[i.mvtype]:
        movietimes[i.mvtype][dt] = []
    movietimes[i.mvtype][dt].append(i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```

will give you something like this:

```
"3D": {
        "2015-01-29": [
                    "2015-01-29T01:20:00.000000Z",
                    "2015-01-29T03:10:00.000000Z"
                    "2015-01-29T05:10:00.000000Z"
        ], 

        "2015-01-28": [
                    "2015-01-28T17:10:00.000000Z",
                    "2015-01-28T01:20:00.000000Z"
        ], 
    }
```